# Request Timeout whist I was creating an attribute set based on default

Tags: attributes

Please help I got this error whilst i was creating an attribute set based on default.

Please see attached of what i was trying to do and also the error page.[image]

Comment: I can't see any error here. Have you tried looking into Magento's logs and Apache's logs?

Comment: here is the error I get once i click the add attribute set button                "This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'. No i have not looked into the magento and apache log, please how do i check?

Comment: I have checked the magento log there is nothing there that relates to the error i got.

Comment: Someone please help! not sure why I am having problem adding a new attribute set basing it on default.